# XSLT: Replace multiple chars in a string

Tags: xslt

I have the following String, which represents days of the week:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

I'd like to replace those values with:

```
M, Tu, W, ...
```

I don't know that there is an XSLT 2.0 function that will handle that in one shot. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: Not one function, but can't you do it with nested `replace`'s, one for each day of the week? Actually you can do M, W, F with a `translate` so you just need two replaces to deal with Tu and Th (and Sa, Su, if you're dealing with weekends too).

Comment: Also, what is the context? Is the string the value of an element or attribute? Is it always `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` or does it vary?

Comment: XSLT 2.0. The string is a node value, and can be a combination of any of those values: "1, 3" or "2, 4, 5" or "2", ... I'm grabbing it from the node, and want to convert to "M, Tu, ..." for display on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to C. M. Sperberg-McQueen's answer only using a sequence as the variable...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <x>1, 2, 3, 4, 5</x>
    <x>1, 3, 5</x>
    <x>2, 4</x>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="daysOfWeek" select="('M','Tu','W','Th','F','Sa','Su')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x">
        <x>
            <xsl:value-of select="for $n in tokenize(.,',') 
                return $daysOfWeek[position()=number(normalize-space($n))]" 
                separator=", "/>        
        </x>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <x>M, Tu, W, Th, F</x>
   <x>M, W, F</x>
   <x>Tu, Th</x>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in function in XSLT that will take a comma-delimited string with numerals in the range 1-7 (or 0-6) and return a comma-delimited sequence of the corresponding one- or two-character abbreviations of the days of the week.  You'll have to use more than one function call.

Assuming for simplicity that you're in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="daynames" as="element(day)*">
  <day n="1">M</day>
  <day n="2">Tu</day>
  <day n="3">W</day>
  <day n="4">Th</day>
  <day n="5">F</day>
  <day n="6">Sa</day>
  <day n="7">Su</day>
</

<xsl:variable name="string" value="'1, 2, 3, 4, 5'"/>

<xsl:value-of select="string-join(
  for $n in tokenize($string,', ') return $days[@n=$n]/string(),
  ', ')"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0, this will be a little more verbose, but can be done with a recursive named template.